# Convert SQL Server stored procedure to Oracle stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, stored-procedures

Hi I am very new to Oracle, please help me to convert the below SQL Server stored procedure to an Oracle stored procedure.

Below is shown the SQL Server stored procedure that I am trying to convert to Oracle, but due to little time I am not able to find a solution, please help me.

```
Create PROCEDURE dbo.myprocedure
    @name          VarChar(50),
    @columnid  VarChar(50),
    @max   Int OUTPUT

AS
 DECLARE @period int,
         @myStatement  varChar(255)
 SET @period = 99999
 SET @max   = 0

 Create Table #newtable
 (
   valu INT
 )

 SET @myStatement  = 'Insert INTO #newtable(valu) SELECT max( ' + @columnid + ') FROM ' + @name + ' WHERE ' + 

@columnid+ ' <= ' + Convert(varChar(5), @period)
 EXEC ( @myStatement )
 SELECT @max = valu FROM  #newtable

 IF (@max = @period)
    SET @max =-1
 ELSE
    SET @max= @max+ 1   
 DROP Table #newtable

GO
```

this  is how i changed into oracle stored procedure

```
Create Table newtable(   valu INT );
CREATE OR REPLACE
PROCEDURE PROCEDURE1
( name IN VARCHAR2
, columnid  IN VARCHAR2
, maxid IN OUT VARCHAR2
)
as
         period number;
         mystatement  varChar(255);   
   BEGIN
  period:= 99999; 
maxid:= 0;

  mystatement:= 'Insert INTO newtable(valu) SELECT max(columnid) FROM name WHERE columnid  <=  Convert(varChar(5), period)';  

 SELECT maxid = valu FROM  newtable;

   EXECUTE immediate mystatement;

 IF (maxid= period)
    return maxid:=-1;
 ELSE

    return maxid:=  maxid + 1;  

 DROP Table newtable;

END PROCEDURE1;
```

Comment: the above works fine in sql server. i want to write the same in oracle. i dont know how?

Comment: Echoing @DStanley - go ahead and try to write it in PL/SQL. Then highlight specific particular aspects that don't work for you. It is not reasonable to ask for every detail to be done for you as that would be very un-SO.

Comment: If you look at the original, all it's doing is getting the maximum value from one column in one table.  I would figure out how to do _that_ in PL-SQL versus just blindly trying to convert syntactically.

Answer (score 4):

Well, creating and dropping tables should be in execute immediate clauses too, procedures doesn't return values and so on. You really should consider reading at least something about PL/SQL and dynamic SQL in Oracle.
This is working example of your procedure in Oracle, but I have no clue, why you would do such a simple task in such complex way:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MyProcedure(p_name VarChar2,p_columnid  VarChar2,p_max OUT NUMBER)
AUTHID CURRENT_USER IS
 v_period NUMBER;
 v_max NUMBER;
BEGIN
 v_period := 99999;
 v_max := 0;

 EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'Create Table newtable (valu NUMBER)';

 EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'Insert INTO newtable (valu) ((SELECT max(' || p_columnid || ') FROM ' || p_name || ' WHERE '
         || p_columnid || ' <= ' || TO_CHAR(v_period) || '))';
 EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT valu FROM newtable' INTO v_max;

 IF (v_max = v_period) THEN
    p_max := -1;
 ELSE
    p_max := v_max + 1;
 END IF;
 EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP Table newtable';
END MyProcedure;
```

---

An example of calling it:

```
DECLARE
 v_tmp NUMBER;
 v_table VARCHAR2(32);
 v_column VARCHAR2(32);
BEGIN
 v_table := 'SOME_TABLE';
 v_column := 'SOME_COLUMN';
 MyProcedure(v_table,v_column,v_tmp);
 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_tmp);
END;
```